# $[E:F]$ can be divided by $|Gal(E/F)| $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Assume that $E$ and $F$ are fields, and $E$ is a finite extension over $F$. Then how to prove that  $[E:F]$ can be divided by $|Gal(E/F)| $? I want to prove it by induction on $[E:F]$. For the case $n=1$ is obvious. Suppose that $[E:F]<N$ is correct, then for the case $[E:F]<N$, we assume that $E=F(u_1,u_2,...,u_n)$. Thus, we can get $[E:F]=[E:F(u_1)][F(u_1):F]$. By induction, we have $|Gal(E:F(u_1))||[E:F(u_1)]$ and $|Gal(F(u_1):F)||[F(u_1):F]$. So if we can prove that $|Gal(E:F(u_1))||Gal(F(u_1):F)|)$ can be divided by $|Gal(E/F)| $, then we will finish the proof. Could any one help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If $K\subset E$ is the fixed field of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ then $[E:K]=\lvert \operatorname{Gal}(E/F)\rvert$, as $E/K$ is Galois, and $[E:F]=[E:K][K:F]$.

Comment: my answer stopped being relevant after the question was edited